# How to compute Franck-Condon Factors for spin-orbit states?

Tags: spectroscopy

I am computing Franck-Condon Factors between the neutral ground state and cationic states to simulate the photoelectron spectra (using Gaussian 16, freq=FCHT). The target cationic state is a pi state and has 3/2 and 1/2 spin-orbit components. I have done optimization and frequency calculation for the pi state in TDDFT. Thus I have FCF for the pi state before spin-orbit splitting. How do I compute FCF two spin-orbit components ? In another word, how can one optimize the two different components of a spin-orbit state. I used the same FCFs for both the components separated by the SOC. It provided reasonable agreement with experiment, however, I wonder if there is more accurate way of doing it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the photo-electron spectrum that you are comparing it to well resolved enough to distinguish effects from spin-orbit coupling?

Comment: Yes, the spin-orbit coupling is quite high and the components are well separated. Each component has associated vibronic lines.